# What is the difference between SHA256WITHRSA and SHA256WITHRSAENCRYPTION digest algorithms?

Tags: hash, rsa, signature, sha-256

I installed djigzo on my android phone and I want to use it for smime mail.
I don't know the difference between choosing `SHA256WITHRSA` and `SHA256WITHRSAENCRYPTION` digest algorithms in the settings.

My online search only returned OIDs and code samples. Can you enlighten me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that djigzo uses [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org) and if you look in the source at the `DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder`, e.g., [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk16/1.46/org/bouncycastle/operator/DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.java), then you find:

```
algorithms.put("SHA256WITHRSAENCRYPTION", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption);
algorithms.put("SHA256WITHRSA", PKCSObjectIdentifiers.sha256WithRSAEncryption);
```

Thus, it seems that both refer to `sha256WithRSAEncryption`, which means RSA with SHA-256 and PKCS #1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: So the two options are the same.
Then why there is a choice to be made?
Are there many RSA with SHA256 algorithms to choose from with different OIDs ?

Comment: It seems that these are two aliases for the same OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11 (or do you have a different one?). Another choice when signing with RSA is the RSA probabilistic signature scheme (PSS) with OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.10.